# If $f$ is locally Lipschitz and differentiable around $x$, is $f'$ continuous at $x$?

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions, frechet-derivative

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $X$ is a Banach space. $f$ is called locally Lipschitz around $\overline{x}$ if there exist $L > 0$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $\overline{x}$ such that
$$\|f(x) - f(x')\| \leqslant L\|x - x'\|, \quad \text{for all} ~ x,x' \in U.$$

As I mentioned on the title, assume that $f$ is locally Lipschitz around $\overline{x}$ and differentiable on a neighborhood of $\overline{x}$.

1. Is $f'$ necessarily continuous at $\overline{x}$?
2. Is $f'$ locally Lipschitz around $\overline{x}$?

**Edit 1:** $f$ is now differentiable on a neighborhood of $\overline{x}$. This is my proof for part 1.

Let $u \in X$, $x_n \to \overline{x}$ and $y_n = f'(x_n)u$. We will show that $y_n$ converges to $f'(\overline{x})u$. The Lipschitz property of $f$ ensures the boundedness of $(y_n)$, then by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $(y_n)$ has a subsequence (denoted the same as $(y_n)$) converges to some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Because $y_n = f'(x_n)u$, there exist $h_{n(k)} := \|x_n - \overline{x}\|^\frac{1}{2}$ and $u_k \in X$ such that, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation}
 \|u_k - u\| < \dfrac{1}{k}, \quad \|y_{n(k)} - y_n\| < \dfrac{1}{k}, \quad \text{where} ~  y_{n(k)} := \dfrac{f(x_n + h_{n(k)}u) - f(x_n)}{h_{n(k)}}.
\end{equation}
Setting
\begin{equation}
 y'_{n(k)} := \dfrac{f(\overline{x} + h_{n(k)}u) - f(\overline{x})}{h_{n(k)}},
\end{equation}
it is needed to verify that $y'_{n(k)} \to y_n$ (as $k \to \infty$) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Due to the Lipschitz continuity of $f$, there exists $L > 0$ such that, for $k$ large enough,
\begin{align}
 \|y'_{n(k)} - y_{n(k)}\| &= \dfrac{1}{h_{n(k)}} \|f(\overline{x} + h_{n(k)}u) - f(x_n + h_{n(k)}u) + f(x_n) - f(\overline{x})\| \\
 &\leqslant \dfrac{1}{h_{n(k)}} \big(\|f(\overline{x} + h_{n(k)}u) - f(x_n + h_{n(k)}u)\| + \|f(x_n) - f(\overline{x})\|\big) \\
 &\leqslant \dfrac{1}{h_{n(k)}} \cdot 2L \cdot \|x_n - \overline{x}\| = 2L \cdot \sqrt{h_{n(k)}}.
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
 \|y'_{n(k)} - y_n\| \leqslant \|y'_{n(k)} - y_{n(k)}\| + \|y_{n(k)} - y_n\| < 2L \cdot \sqrt{h_{n(k)}} + \dfrac{1}{k}.
\end{equation}
The right-hand side tends to $0$, which means $y'_{n(k)}$ tends to $y_n$ as $k \to \infty$. Letting $n \to \infty$, one gets $y'_{n(k)} \to y$. By the setting of $y'_{n(k)}$, it follows that $y = f'(\overline{x})u$.

Comment: Pretty sure you missed the $L$ on the RHS of the inequality.  Also, t his is a problem statement question (PSQ), we typically want you to show some of your own effort.   Here's a link about it https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq?cb=1

Comment: thank you for pointing out my mistake, I've just edited it and added my proof.

Comment: Good job, welcome to MSE!

Comment: There are some typos: the argument $u$ is missing everywhere, i.e., $f(x+h_{nk}u)$. Also the inequality signs in the last formula contain a typo.

Comment: You cannot choose $h_{n(k)} = \|x_n -\bar x\|^{1/2}$. One can only guarantee $h_{n(k)} \color{red}\le \|x_n -\bar x\|^{1/2}$. This proof does not work.

Comment: Totally agree with you, Daw. I forgot that $\|x_n - \overline{x}\|^{1/2}$ does not depend on $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Here is a counterexample. Take
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 \sin(x^{-1}) & \text{ if } x\ne 0,\\
0 & \text{ if } x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \sin(x^{-1}) - \cos(x^{-1}) & \text{ if } x\ne 0,\\
0 & \text{ if } x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f'$ is bounded on bounded intervals, hence $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous (by mean-value theorem). However, $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank for your reply. However, I don't think $f$ is locally Lipschitz around $\overline{x}$. Indeed, let $x_{1n} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\pi}{2} + n.2\pi}$ and $x_{2n} = \dfrac{1}{n^3.2\pi}$, one deduces that
 $$\dfrac{f(x_{1n}) - f(x_{2n})}{x_{1n} - x_{2n}} \to \infty$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @XuânDuyBảoNguyễn you got that limit wrong: it is zero. Local Lipschitz continuity follows from mean value theorem, which only needs differentiability of $f$, and boundedness of $f'$.

Comment: thank Daw, you're completely right, I've just double checked, and see it more clearly now.